# How does the IRS define non-compliance?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, terminology

How does the IRS define non-compliance? If an individual taxpayer makes a typo of $1 on a tax form, does the IRS consider that person to be non-compliant? Is there a scope of actions that the word encompasses, or is compliance considered nothing short of filing all required forms and attachments with no errors in entry or calculation?

Comment: The point is that since they as a matter of routine round up or down the number to avoid decimals, accuracy is a matter of whether or not you are grossly under or over reporting something for the sake of a benefit that would come from it. Simple as that, if the end of the day nothing would have changed in the outcome, then it is effectively moot.

Comment: The point I was referring to was the point of the question.  The question is intending to ask of the IRS definition of compliance, not the specific case in the title.  I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: If you're suggesting that any error in entry or calculation is effectively moot if at the end of the day nothing would have changed in the outcome, by all means source that and make it an answer.  (though that in itself doesn't give a definition of compliance...)

Comment: Do you have an example of the IRS using the word "non-compliance"?

Comment: No, I don't, but I have found examples of them using the word "compliance" which implies a definition for "non-compliance"; for the sake of clarity though I should have used "compliance".  I apologize for the confusing wording.

Comment: That's fine, can you share those examples? I searched the IRC but the only references I found to compliance or lack thereof were things like retirement plans and health plans that did or didn't comply with specific regulations.

Comment: For example, I now searched irs.gov for "compliance" and the fourth link looks to be the earliest that applies to individuals. https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p3114.pdf

Comment: @saxomophone That very document says that a "compliance check" is mostly for businesses, is neither an inspection nor an audit, and is voluntary.

Comment: The first paragraph on page one states "an individual" as the subject.  But not to belabor the point about that particular document...I understand that your interpretation is that the IRS does not consider "compliance" as a formal concept applicable to individuals.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 6):

Internal Revenue Code section 7201 says:

> Any person who willfully attempts in any manner to evade or defeat any tax imposed by this title or the payment thereof shall, in addition to other penalties provided by law, be guilty of a felony and, upon conviction thereof, shall be fined not more than $100,000 ($500,000 in the case of a corporation), or imprisoned not more than 5 years, or both, together with the costs of prosecution.

A typo isn't willful and so does not meet the definition of tax evasion.

The IRS further states

> For individuals, a substantial understatement of tax applies if you
> understate your tax liability by 10% of the tax required to be shown
> on your tax return or $5,000, whichever is greater.

$1 is less than $5,000, so you wouldn't even owe a penalty for the fact of underreporting. (If they discover it after your tax payment was due, they could charge you a late payment penalty.)

Comment: Thank you for the sources.  Is non-compliance simply a synonym for tax evasion?

Comment: @saxomophone No, it's not really a synonym. I am mostly ignoring the word "compliance" and answering the majority / body of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful insight.